# ARIMA loss of effectiveness due to non-Gaussianity

Tags: regression, references, arima, misspecification

I am looking for references regarding to loss of effectiveness of ARIMA due to different misspecification. For instance the following article:

- Chung Chen and George C. Tiao Journal of Business & Economic Statistics Vol. 8, No. 1 (Jan., 1990), pp. 83-97

tells what happens if there is random level shifts in data, but they are ignored and approximated by original ARIMA model.

The following:

- Johannes Ledolter, International Journal of Forecasting, Vol. 5, No. 2, 1989, pp. 231-240

tells what happens if there is random outlier ignored.

What I am looking for (and failed to find) is what happens when 
the data is not Gaussian. Imagine, that Box-Cox transformation has been performed not carefully and we use not optimal arguments. Or, even with proper Box-Cox transformation, it is not guaranteed that our initial data were distributed by Box-Cox power law exactly, then our transformed data are not normal exactly.

What will be estimators of forecast variance increase (decrease?) and bias increase in this case?

Comment: @kjetil Why are you editing nearly every old post being brought by by the community?

Comment: In this case retagging for the new tag `misspecification`